# File handling in C++ gives .exe stopped working error

Tags: c++, file

I have basic file handling code of reading file named"student.dat" using visual studio.

the output reads the file and displays the result in console but visual studio pops up the dialog as

[image]

code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
class student
{
            int admno;
           // char name[20];
            string name;
public:
          void getdata()
          {
                     cout<<"\n\nEnter The Name of The Student ";
                     //gets(name);
                     cin>>name;
                     getch();
                     cout<<"\nEnter The admission no. ";
                     cin>>admno;


                     // getch();
          }
          void showdata()
          {
                     cout<<"\nAdmission no. : "<<admno;
                     cout<<"\nStudent Name : ";
                     cout<<name;
                     //puts(name);

          }
          int retadmno()
          {
                     return admno;
          }


};


int main()
{


    student obj;
          ifstream fp1;
          fp1.open("student.dat",ios::binary);
          while(fp1.read((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj)))
          {
                     obj.showdata();
          }

          fp1.close();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to store/load an object to a file, which is invalid.

```
while(fp1.read((char*)&obj,sizeof(obj)))
```

Objects may contain references to memory (std::string e.g.) that are invalid after loading. You have to provide serialization for your objects or use plain structs without pointers or references to store your data. E.g.:

```
struct {
    int      admno;
    char[20] name;
}
```

If you need strings with variable length, you may use a string store:

```
struct {
    int     admno;
    size_t  name_index;
}

std::vector<std::string> names;
```

To store, iterate over your names and save length and `.c_str` of each `std::string`. To read, do it the other way around and read length into n, read n bytes into a buffer and construct a `std::string` out of the buffer.

You might have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to load raw data only to some POD objects. This line is an error:

```
fp1.read( (char*)&obj,sizeof(obj) );
```

because `student` contains `std::string`. `std::string` contains a pointer to a memory block which becomes invalid and totally useless after the object is destroyed. It means the data you  load to `std::string` is just a garbage.

I'd think about object serialization. [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is a good way to start.

Answer (score 0):

You never call `GetData` so `admno` is not instantiated in `ShowData`